# Swipe to Delete unable to bind data

Tags: android

I am using this `'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'` 3rd party library for recyclerview swipe to delete an item

myclick listener is as below:

```
  holder.deleteLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            removeItem(position);




        }
    });
```

Based on my condition i wrote delete logic

```
     public void removeItem(int position) {
    Batchinfo batchinfo = abc.get(position);
    Iterator it = abcd.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
         Batchinfo a = (Batchinfo) pair.getValue();
        if(a.getBatchId().equalsIgnoreCase(batchinfo.getBatchId()))
        {
            ExpandableAdapter.quantityadded.remove(pair.getKey());

            break;
        }

    }
```

Here ExpandableAdapter.quantityadded is a static hashmap .

but unable to delete the view ...any help ???

Answer (score 0):

try this out! 
you just replace your this

```
  holder.deleteLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
    @Override       
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        removeItem(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   
 });
```

Comment: i have already implemeted....that lib ....but the only prob is to know how to remove the view after deletion....

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged(); after removing items

Comment: in that library  it is like..notifyitemremoved(getadapterposition)   so what i done is  @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inputs, viewGroup, false);
        final ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }  public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItem(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());




            }

Comment: okay is it deleting from you List? and not deleting the view! or not doing any thing

Comment: but in your code its is missing na notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());

Comment: for view you need to notify you just calll these two methods this will work notifyItemRemoved(position);
      notifyItemRangeChanged(position, recentModelsList.size());